# Default XP SP3 %SYSTEMROOT% permissions

Tags: windows, windows-xp, permissions

What should the default output of

```
C\>CACLS %SYSTEMROOT%
```

look like under XP Home SP3?

(There's a *karma bounty* if you can answer this before my spouse returns.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\WINDOWS BUILTIN\Users:R
       BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(special access:)
                                 GENERIC_READ
                                 GENERIC_EXECUTE

       BUILTIN\Power Users:C
       BUILTIN\Power Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)C
       BUILTIN\Administrators:F
       BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:F
       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
       BUILTIN\Administrators:F
       CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
```

Comment: That looks good, thanks.  I'm having a little trouble specifying some of the finer-grained ACLs with `CACLS.EXE`, but you'll get the victory if/when I survive a reboot.